# Why do we have that $Bir(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1)=Aut(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm reading the notes where the following statement is assumed to be a well-known result:

Why is any birational map which maps the projective line $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ onto itself belongs to $Aut(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1)$?

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Briefly, a rational mapping from an algebraic curve to the projective line may be represented locally as $[p(z) : q(z)]$ for some _one-variable_ polynomials $p$ and $q$. Any common factors ("potential points of indeterminacy") may be divided out, yielding a holomorphic extension. By contrast, a rational mapping in two or more variables can have genuine indeterminacy, e.g., of the type $f(z, w) = z/w$ at the origin. <> This is surely explained elsewhere on-site, hence the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Georges' answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83233/doing-complex-analysis-on-the-riemann-sphere) may be of interest.

Comment: This is also available as the "curve-to-projective extension theorem" in section 16.5 of [Vakil's Rising Sea](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).